# Are the prinicples the same for designing a high side vs low side buck?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, buck

I am an analog engineer that is getting into SMPS design.

This is a high side buck:

[image: schematic]

This is a low side buck:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBgZup.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Assuming that I take care of the voltages for the FET, are the circuits equivalent if I use a tool to design a high side buck?

More specifically: There are plenty of tools to design high side bucks, but they never have low sides to quickly design low side buck circuits. Can I use a tool to find output power, voltage, frequency, ect. But then roll that into a low side buck design. Would loop compensation be the same?

Comment: Yes, provided you have differential measurements of output voltage and switch/inductor current.

Comment: It depends on the load; if it's a simple resistor then they are the same if all you are interested in is heating stuff.

Comment: This is just an example circuit, Usually SMPS texts represent the load or variable loads with a simple resistor.